# Simple statistical yes/no classifier in WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka

In order for me to compare my results of my research in labeled text classification, I need to have a baseline to compare with. One of my colleagues told me one solution would be to make the most easiest and dumbest classifier possible. The classifier makes a decision based on the frequency of a particular label. 
This means that, when in my dataset I have a total of 100 samples and when it knows 80% of these samples have the label A, it will classify a sample as 'A' in 80% of the time. Since my entire research is using the Weka API, I have looked into the documentation but unfortunatly haven't found anything about this.

So my question is, is it possible in Weka to implement such a classifier and yes, could someone point out how this is possible? This question is pure informative since I looked into this thing but did not find anything, here is where I hope to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That classifier is already implemented in Weka, it is called ZeroR and simply predicts the most frequent class (in the case of nominal class attributes) or the mean (in the case of numeric class attributes). If you want to know how to implement such a classifier yourself, look at the ZeroR source code.